# clang-tidy warning: an exception may be thrown in function

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

Having this code (`mName` is a member of type `std::string`)

```
//.h
[[nodiscard]] auto name() const noexcept -> std::string;
```

and

```
// .cpp
[[nodiscard]] auto NodeData::name() const noexcept -> std::string {
  return mName;
}
```

clang-tidy is giving the following warning:

```
warning: an exception may be thrown in function 'name' which should not throw exceptions [bugprone-exception-escape]
[[nodiscard]] auto NodeData::name() const noexcept -> std::string {
```

Is it right that the function can throw exceptions in this case? If yes, what is that case?

Comment: Did you declare that inside a class? If you didn't, that actually produces a warning, because a non-member function can't have a `cv-qualifier (const-volatile)`. But since you used the `mName` convention, it seems that way. If you want to suppress the warning, `clang-tidy` actually has a generic mechanism to suppress diagnostics using `NOLINT`.

Comment: `[[nodiscard]] auto NodeData::name() const noexcept -> std::string { try { auto result = mName; return result; } catch(...) { return {}; } }`

Comment: You return a copy, so I guess `std::bad_alloc` can be thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang-tidy is correct in this case. When returning `std::string` by value, the copy constructor is used in this case, which possibly results in [`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) being thrown. It is highly unlikely, but technically possible.

If you are using C++17, a possible solution (besides removing `noexcept`) is to use `std::string_view` as the result type instead:

```cpp
// note: prior to C++17, consider const std::string& as a result
[[nodiscard]] auto name() const noexcept -> std::string_view;
```

The construction of a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) involves no heap allocations, making it safe to mark this function `noexcept`. However, since the view doesn't own the string data, you would have to make sure that you don't use the view after the string goes out of scope.

In general, you should seriously consider whether you need getters/setters at all. As you can see, getters add problems such as:

- getters allocating memory and possibly throwing, or
- having to think carefully about lifetimes, or
- using reference counting (which isn't cheap, and can introduce memory leaks)

Perhaps the best solution is not to use a getter at all, which is perfectly valid in C++.

Comment: Returning a `string_view` is very error prone. Reference qualifiers fits more to the situation. (`const string& get() const& noexcept` and `string get() && noexcept`, they should come in pair to avoid dangling reference)

Comment: @Burak How is returning reference less error-prone than returning `std::string_view`?In both cases you need to ensure lifetime of the owner of data is longer than last use of returned view.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen If user calls `get` on a temporary, `&&` overload is called; so the returned string is PRValue, therefore no lifetime issue occurs. (`const string& str = MyClass().get();` lifetime extension occurs) If the function is called on an LValue object and assigned to a new string instance, copy constructor is called at user site, therefore exception does not belong to `get` function. (`string str = my_class.get();`) If the result is assigned to a reference, user is explicitly holding a reference and is aware of such issues. (`const string& str = my_class.get();`)

Answer (score 1):

As you return a `std::string` object by value, you will invoke the copy-constructor of `std::string` which is not `noexcept`, as it may throw (failing memory allocation).